# Only one time openable file

Tags: file

I am not a programmer and I don't know how to code. I will be starting to learn learning within a few months. I had this idea about a file that self-deletes while closing the file after its opened one time. This is similar to the whatsapp "view once" option.

My reason for this file is when I came across freshers or some experienced persons applying for jobs, for example creating a 3D models of an enclosure or structures. In this, some or many companies in the interview ask to make "particular" projects to the description they give. They have to follow the description by making the model and explanation, and finally send them. Then they get rejected. It's like a "free" work trick from some companies. Please don't get me wrong, I am just asking if it's possible. Maybe this type of file is applicable in other usages.

If this is possible, I will create it after learning to code. It's just a question of "possible or not". Sorry if this wastes your time. (sorry if I put the wrong tags)

Comment: No, it's generally not possible unless you control the device on which the file is opened. Also, the interviewing projects I've seen are all toy projects and not meant for production. I'd be very wary about applicants writing any production code for me. You also may want to check [ask].

Comment: @Robert Sorry, my grammar skills are not that good as it's not my native language. Thank you for clearing my doubt.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes theoritically, a 3d model is just data, you could encrypt it like any other data, and then use a software layer that could decrypt the data with the appropriate key.

I guess you can make your models visible only through the said software and make it impossible to export the decrypted data.

Keep in mind it will always be possible for anyone motivated/skilled enough to break/exploit/reverse engineer a piece of software.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But it's not the answer I was looking for, because i was asking about modifing a 3d model file making it as "view only once" file. It's work is to just openable for one time, then after closing it, it will delete itself after that. Sorry for my grammar or any incorrect explaination.

Comment: a 3d model being a model (a descriptive file and not executable code) it cannot do things on its own, that would be a huge security risk for any OS, so I would say no for this particular case :) for me you always have to delegate the logic (here the delete) to the software using the file